# How to fix TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.int32 != tf.float32 with tensorflow using PyGad?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, genetic-algorithm

I have defined a new layer to be put as an input layer using Keras. The code is:

```
class layer(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):
def __init__(self):
    super(layer, self).__init__()
    H_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    self.H = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=H_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"),
        trainable=True,
    )
    b_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.b = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=b_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
    )
    n_init = tf.zeros_initializer()
    self.n = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=n_init(shape=(1,), dtype="float32"), trainable=True
    )


def call(self, z):
    return self.H**2 / (1+(1/self.b)**(2/self.n)) *(1+((1+z)/self.b)**(2/self.n))
```

I intend to put this layer as input in my generation callback function, which is

```
   `def callback_generation(ga_instance):
         print("Generation"= {generation}".format(generation=ga_instance.generations_completed))
    print("Fitness    = 
{fitness}".format(fitness=ga_instance.best_solution()[1]))





inputs = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="inputs")
targets = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(1,), name="targets")
logits = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(15)(inputs)
predictions = layer(name="predictions")(logits, targets)

model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets], 
outputs=predictions)

data = {
    "inputs": z,
    "targets": H_z,
}

model = tensorflow.keras.Sequential(inputs=input_layer, 
outputs=output_layer)

weights_vector = 
tensorflow.pygad.kerasga.model_weights_as_vector(model=model)

keras_ga = pygad.kerasga.KerasGA(model=model,
                                 num_solutions=12)


model.summary()`
```

This gives me an error reporting that the `tf__call()` method takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given.

This is the detailed error traceback:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most 
    recent call last)
    <ipython-input-101-e09c7d4f3228> in <module>
         20 targets = tensorflow.keras.Input(shape=(1,), 
    name="targets")
         21 logits = tensorflow.keras.layers.Dense(15)(inputs)
    ---> 22 predictions = layer(name="predictions")(logits, 
    targets)
         23 
         24 model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs, targets], 
    outputs=predictions)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in 
    __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, 
    args, kwargs, input_list):
        951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, 
    args, kwargs,
    --> 952                                                 
    input_list)
        953 
        954     # Maintains info about the `Layer.call` stack.

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in 
    _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, 
    input_list)
       1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer 
    building, e.g. input shape.
       1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
    -> 1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
       1092 
       1093         if outputs is None:

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in 
    _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, 
    kwargs)
        820       return 
    nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
        821     else:
    --> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, 
    kwargs, input_masks)
        823 
        824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, 
   kwargs, input_masks):

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
    packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in 
    _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, 
    input_masks)
        861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or 
    have we already done it?
        862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
    --> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
        864 
        865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, 
    outputs)

    ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- 
   packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in 
    wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
        668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad- 
    except
        669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
    --> 670           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
        671         else:
        672           raise
     TypeError: in user code:


     TypeError: tf__call() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Could you share the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Did you use integer gene data type in PyGAD? It is better to share the PyGAD code and more about the error.

Comment: I have edited the question with the complete error statement

Comment: @AhmedGad the last section of the question was deleted. I do not know how to print the fitness value after line 1187.

Comment: @KoushikiBhattacharyya, you can implement the on_fitness callback method to print the fitness values.